# Why 'Unknwn.h' instead of 'Unknown.h'? Is it misprint?

Tags: c++, c, com, library-design

Why is Microsoft's COM header file named as [`Unknwn.h`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), instead of `Unknown.h`? Is it misprint, or are there objective reasons for such naming?

Comment: @PaulManta According to the tags, I would say COM.

Comment: Some employers ban the use of the letter `o`. In some cases it's to avoid confusion with the Arabic numeral for "five", and in others it may be for ethical or religious reasons.

Comment: @KerrekSB: surely you must be joking.

Comment: @nightcracker If anything to avoid confusion between o and 0. But this question is ridiculous.

Comment: was it originally written to be compatible with some odd/old filesystem?

Comment: I think it's an interesting question, and I would like to know why. I voted to reopen.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel i'm also curious. people who have been programming decades longer than i remember such historical facts. (so did i)

Comment: @Etienne de Martel Is the answer for this question is interesting to nobody? :)

Comment: @Bush: The question _is_ interesting.  Unfortunately, it was a bad question because it's poorly worded and impossible to answer.

Comment: @Florin Stingaciu It is unconvincing.
Then why the other header has a name 'iostream' instead of 'istream'?

Comment: @Bush There are two headers: `istream` _and_ `iostream`.

Comment: Hey guys, this not just some unknow header, this is **the** unknown interface, so it **needs** to have some kind of individidual name, so why not remove the `o`, removing the `u` whould have been worth.

Comment: Wording can be fixed, @Mooing, as you demonstrated. What makes you think it's impossible to answer? Why did you vote to close the question after you voted to re-open it?

Comment: @alk: probably I would have chosen "IUnknown.h". Unambiguous, has the same name of the interface and also complies to 8.3 restrictions.

Comment: @RobKennedy: I voted to open because I saw it was closed as not constructive, and thought "it _is_ constructive".  Then after it was open, I eventually realized this is "too localized", and voted to close again.  :(

Comment: Author implies that we know the answer -  **U** n **k** n **w** n --> U know Why... `n`s are padding the brotherhood uses to convey cryptic message like this. There's also a movie coming up - `U know why...Britney did it again?` nuff said about the legacy of this header

Comment: Probably like that to avoid conflict with an existing Unknown.h header (a big file at Microsoft :)

Comment: @GrahamPerks: Do you work for Microsoft?  Or do you have a citation for that?

Comment: Six letter filenames go back a long, long way: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Radix-50

Comment: I'm just guessing on a conflict with an existing unknown.h header. Sorry I wasn't clear on that.

Comment: Short of someone from the language team coming and answering this question, I don't see how it could ever be answered definitively. And let's say they did, *Does it matter why?* Is this a specific programming problem you face? It would seem to be a trivia-esque question, and those aren't a good fit for Stack Overflow.  Perhaps you'd be better off Emailing [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing)?

Comment: [Meta discussion about this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153440/is-an-unlikely-to-be-answered-question-the-same-as-an-unanswerable-question). Please do not delete this question while it is being discussed on meta!